# Can't see Java Working Set Folder Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, directory

I have a little problem and I hope someone can help me.

I'm using Eclipse, and i'm trying to add a Java Working Set folder to my Workspace.

The problem is that when I try to do it (right click, new, Java Working Set, and set the name) the first time works fine, but I can't see any change in the workspace (no folder appear), I have tryed to refresh the workspace but it doesn't work (and close and open Eclipse).

When I try to create it again, it says: "a working set with that name already exists", but I can't see it.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working Sets are not folders, they are just a collection of objects.

You may be thinking about how Package Explorer displays projects. You can tell Package Explorer to show Working Sets by selecting 'Top Level Elements > Working Sets' in the view menu (click the small down pointing triangle at the top right of the view).

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know what it really was, thank you for explaining it. The problem was the problem was I had to select the folders in the tab you told me (the small down triangle-->select working set)